# FitNesse Slim: Passing varargs in script table

Tags: fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

Right now I am running the java version of FitNesse 20130530.
I would like to have a method in my fixture that have variable arguments, like:

```
public class VarArgTester {
    public void testVarargs(Object... newData) {
    [...]
    }
}
```

and to call it like

```
!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}

!|import|
|VarArgTester|

!|script|VarArgTester|
|test varargs;|9999|fitnesse|01-Jan-1970|
```

Right now I get following error message:

```
Method testVarargs[3] not found in package.name.VarArgTester.
```

So, it seems like this functionality is not implemented. But if so, how do I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slim doesn't support variable arguments.  The best you can do is write wrapper methods with fixed arguments.

```
public void testOneArg(Object arg1) { testArgs(arg1); }
public void testTwoArgs(Object arg1, Object arg2) { testArgs(arg1, arg2); }
```

Comment: I had a look in the source yesterday and I can second that.

I thought that adding `method.isVarArgs()` in `findMathcingMethod` to could do the trick but since FitNesse is converting the arguments and thereby calls `method.getParameterTypes()` it was not possible.

A solution might be to create a custom Converter that handles Object[] and then take care of the proper conversion in my fixture.